# Override getPreferredSize and PaintComponent method, why?

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

just beginning to learn java and was playing around with Jframes, Jpanels and Graphics and was wondering why is it that we must override the getPreferredSize and PaintComponent method to make a graphics object appear in the Jpanel that has been added to a Jframe?

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for  step by step examples of how to do custom painting for basic information about painting. `just beginning to learn java`  - keep a link to the tutorial handy as most basic Swing concepts are explained with examples.

Answer (score 3):

You don't "need" to, but it sure will help.

A base component (like `JPanel` and `JComponent`) has a `preferredSize` of `0x0`, which, when used with some layout managers, makes the component virtually invisible (in fact, the painting sub system won't even paint a component which has a size of `0x0`).

In everyday use, they calculate their `preferredSize` through the layout manager that is applied to them, which uses the child components to calculate the result.

So, in the absence of child components, you need to provide appropriate sizing hints, so when you use something like `JFrame#pack`, you don't end up with a "flat packed" window or sit around for a few hours wondering why you awesome component won't show up

Comment: Ahhhh I see thank you very much just to clarify graphics object != component and also the preferredsize method is called in a behind the scenes essence by the layout manager?

Comment: Yes, `Graphics` is not a `Component`, it's just a means by which the component can paint itself. And yes, `getPreferredSize` is called "behind the scenes"